# Need help debugging website in IE8-

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, debugging, testing

I need help checking if the site works correctly in IE. I'm usually testing with IETester but it constantly crashes for me now, and since i need to see the site live i can't rely on screenshots from services like Browserlab etc.

URL:
http://goo.gl/Fk29R

I need to know if the slideshow next to the big blue buttons works correctly. Each image is suppose to show for 4 seconds, then fade out for 1.5 seconds. There are three images, when it reaches the last one it should loop from the beginning again.

Can anyone check if it works or not? Maybe check the console for errors if not working?

Comment: Sorry, but this is off topic on Stack Overflow, partly for the reasons mentioned here: [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997) Maybe the HTML or JS chat turns up somebody who's willing to help, that's the best channel for stuff like this. (I would take a peek but I don't have a Windows machine handy, either)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site works well with IE9, IE8 and IE7

You may already know this but you can use Internet Explorer 9, press F12 to show the development tools and then switch between broser versions by selecting the "Broser Mode"

Comment: Thank you! I did know that option existed, but i didn't know how to enable it. Do you know how reliable it is?

Comment: I use it quite often, it seems to "emulate" those old browsers just fine.

Comment: @qwerty from personal experience I would say it's about 90% reliable. It gets the job done for most applications. But there are however, just like in any other emulator/simulator software, slight differences between the native version and the 'Browser mode' setting. I don't have an example however.